# Python Selenium Requests not running

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, element

This is my first time using selenium and I'm not really sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
    
driver = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\natem\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
#click
driver.get("https://multiplayer-swordio.sedated.repl.co/")
time.sleep(2)
    
    
driver.find_element_by_id('game').click  
    
time.sleep(2)
name = driver.find_element_by_id('input-form')
name.click()
name.sendKeys("user")
name.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Please post your error traceback so we can help. Also make sure that at line 5 `driver =` isn't a reporting an invalid syntax error. It should looks like `driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved your problem by using below code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard
import time

driver = Webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\natem\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
# click
driver.get("https://multiplayer-swordio.sedated.repl.co/")
time.sleep(2)

# to run this line we need to do ()
driver.find_element_by_id('game').click()

time.sleep(5)
# use xpath insted of id
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/input')
name.click()
name.send_keys("user")
# to press Enter
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
time.sleep(20)
```